# How to add active class on hover and on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing an application where I need to add class `active` for both `hover` and `click` events.
The challenge I am facing here is when I hover my content, it adds the class `active`. There is no problem in that.
Since it is active now, when I am about to click on content it should hold up with the class `active`. But instead it goes to the normal state and it toggles the class.

**JQuery**

```
$("div").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }, function() {
        $( this ).removeClass('active');
    }
);
$( "div" ).click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/866pzu47/)**

Comment: Why are you using javascript for this?

Comment: may be like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5othz63y/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5othz63y/2/ ?

Comment: How about you add a different class or use plain old css with no JavaScript for the hover

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use CSS for the hover event

```
div:hover{background:red;}
```

And remove the hover event from your Javascript:

```
$( "div" ).click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/866pzu47/6/)**

If you want the same functionality without CSS.

Add a second class called `clicked`. Let the hover event check for this class before removing the class.

```
$("div").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }, function() {
        if(!$( this).hasClass('clicked') ){
            $( this ).removeClass('active');
        }
    }
);

$("div").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/866pzu47/25/)**

Comment: i cant do this here since i have different background images with different li

Comment: i tried that already i need solution in jquery

Comment: @Benjamin If you want the same functionality with only jQuery, my updated answer should do the trick.
Also, you might want to update your question to these new standards.

Answer (score 1):

### Pure CSS Solution: - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/866pzu47/11/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div-p">
    <label for="toggle-1"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
    <div id="div"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#div-p {
    position: relative;
}
label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: transparent;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div#div {
    background-color: red !important;
}
#div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
label:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/866pzu47/21/)

If you must use **JS ONLY** .......

If you use a variable `toggleOn` that flips on when `click` event happens, your issue should be solved. You do not need to toggleClass on click since you'll always click while hovered:

```
var toggleOn = false;
$("div").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }, function() {
        toggleOn || $( this ).removeClass('active');
    }
);
$( "div" ).click(function(){
        toggleOn = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you `hover` the `div` and `active` class is added.Now you click, so ideally `active` class should be removed.

For this, Bind `click` with `hover`(*as `mouseenter` and `mouseout`*) as below :

```
 $("div").bind('click mouseenter', function () {
     if ($(this).hasClass("active")) $(this).removeClass("active");
     else $(this).addClass("active");
 });


 $('div').mouseout(function () {
     if ($(this).hasClass("active")) $(this).removeClass("active");
 });
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h37yke8p/)

Comment: @Benjamin : updated...break `hover` into `mouseenter` and `mouseout` and it would work.... now check! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this : use one status variable for hover on or off, use this variable to know the hover status when user clicks on image and toggleClass accordingly.

```
var clicked = false;
var activeByClicked = false;
$("div").hover(
    function() {
        if(!activeByClicked)
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }, function() {
         if(!activeByClicked)
         {
             clicked = false;
        $( this ).removeClass('active');
         }
    }
);
$( "div" ).click(function(){
     if(clicked)
     {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))
        {
            activeByClicked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //clicked = false;
            activeByClicked = false;
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
     }
    else
    {
        clicked = true;
        activeByClicked = true;
    }

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/866pzu47/32/)**

Comment: should add class active on click even when it is hovered and active.

Comment: do you want to add active class on every click or do you want to toggle active class?

Comment: I wanna make it toggle

Comment: here when you hover and click first time, it keeps the active class and when you click second time it toggles active class. Isn't it your requirment?

Comment: No it should add class active even though it hovered and has class active already.

Comment: @Benjamin, if it already has the active class you don't need to add it again. You can't have two active classes. Based on your ridiculous comments and corrections, might I suggest that you haven't explained yourself well in the original question (or that you haven't thought through your problem?). I think it's back to the drawing board...

Comment: I need the hover property on click is there any alternate way to do that.

Comment: @Benjamin, is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/866pzu47/32/) what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what im looking for could you update this is in your answer so i can give you a upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it could all be done in JavaScript with a :hover added to the selected rule, BUT if you want the color to be removed on click, the best option would be to use a second class.

**CSS:**

```
div{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.active, div.hoverActive{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("div").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('hoverActive');
    }, function() {
        $( this ).removeClass('hoverActive');
    }
);
$( "div" ).click(function(){
    var div = $(this);   
    div.toggleClass('active');
    if (!div.is(".active")) {
        div.removeClass("hoverActive");
    }    
});
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/f1p0ahmk/1/

Comment: Sorry i don't want to remove the color on click it just need to append the same class and toggle.

Comment: It is impossible to add the same class when the hover out will remove it. You need some sort of flag that said you want to keep it on. Either a data attribute or another class. What you are trying to do is impossible without some other logic. Try my fiddle if you have not done so.

Comment: The fiddle of yours i done it already and that doesnt help me.

Comment: What is your goal when they click????? To have the active class stick? That is what this does. Reading the other comments, there is some fear over changing the CSS. Is that some requirement.

Comment: yes thats what i`m trying it sticks and toggle.

Comment: Which is what my code does, so unless I am missing something other than the fear/requirement of not altering the css code...

Comment: Yes it does but the hover doesnt works here

Comment: Ah, crap, that was the wrong fiddle...that was your code. lol http://jsfiddle.net/f1p0ahmk/1/

Comment: Thanks man may be that make sense. I need to add another class for hover thats annoying.

Comment: Other option is adding a data attribute...

Comment: That would be great  Im trying to work on that thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Change your click code, since the toggle will be offset by the hover function:

```
$( "div" ).click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("active")) $(this).removeClass("active");
    else $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Yes it does :) http://jsfiddle.net/866pzu47/7/

Comment: My query is simple just to add class active on click even though it is hovered.